# Check if SQL Query Return any Output

Tags: vbscript

I have the following SQL Statement (Running from my VBS script):

> exec DBABee.[Alerting].[usp_TShell] 'SpaceProblems_tempdb_only'

Which return the following output:
[image]

My Question is,
how do i modify my vbs script, to flag when the mention above SQL Statement is returning any result (in this case any rows)? 
and how do i enter the result to a varible?

This is my script:

```
Dim objCN, strConnection
Dim objAPI, oBag , srtReturn
Set objCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objAPI = CreateObject("MOM.ScriptAPI")
Set oBag = objAPI.CreatePropertyBag()
strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=sqlsrv01,1433;Database=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"
objCN.Open strConnection
Dim strSQLQuery
strSQLQuery = "exec DBABee.[Alerting].[usp_TShell] 'SpaceProblems_tempdb_only'"
Dim objRS
Set objRS=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set objRS = objCN.Execute(strSQLQuery)
Do Until objRS.EOF

                if objRS.Fields("IsProblem") <> "0" then

                    Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Good")
                    Call oBag.AddValue("Result", objRS.Fields("IsProblem"))

                else
                    Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Bad")


                end if
                objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
Call objAPI.Return(oBag)
```

I’m not familiar with this area of VBScripting,
So any help, will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RecordCount](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html) attribute to determine if anything was returned by the query. In your case, you could use

```
if (objRS.RecordCount > 0) Then
     ' There is data! 
else
     ' Nothing was returned
end if
```

As for getting a value out of the RecordSet (in your case, objRS), use this:

```
Dim ExampleVar
Do Until ObjRS.EOF
    ExampleVar = objRS.Fields("ColumnName").Value
    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Assuming your AddValue function for oBag is correct, it looks like you are retrieving RecordSet values properly